# Ble Android Advertising: AddServiceData

Tags: android, kotlin, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-ble

on my ble project i'm trying to add some service data to advertise data like this

```
 var data = AdvertiseData.Builder().apply {
            setIncludeDeviceName(true)
            addServiceData(
                ParcelUuid(BleConsts.SERVICE_UUID),
                myData.toByteArray(Charsets.UTF_8)
            )
        }

  bleAdvertiser.startAdvertising(
      settings.build(), 
      data.build(), 
      advertiseCallback
  )
```

but ***onStartFailure*** callback of my ***AdvertiseCallback*** implementation is triggered with error code 1.
If i remove from ***data*** the ***addServiceData*** call, advertise start without any problem.
What's wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Error code 1 corresponds to the constant [`ADVERTISE_FAILED_DATA_TOO_LARGE`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/bluetooth/le/AdvertiseCallback#advertise_failed_data_too_large). Your data must be 31 bytes or less:

> Failed to start advertising as the advertise data to be broadcasted is larger than 31 bytes.

Try reducing the size of the data you are adding.

Comment: Correct, i've removed setIncludeDeviceName and now it works. 
Thank you.

Comment: any onther way to include name ?